# Django - urlpatterns cannot find a module

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and from ASP.NET MVC. I just want to make a folder structure something below, though, if I navigate to http://localhost:8000/community_web/, that gives me an error saying "Could not import community_web.controllers.home. Error was: No module named controllers.home".

Folder structure what I want.

```
<project>
  urls.py
  <community_web>
    urls.py
    <controllers>
      home.py
```

I've added the following codes.
To project.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^community_web/', include('community_web.urls')),
)
```

To project.community_web.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'community_web.controllers.home.index'),
)
```

I thought a views.py would correspond to a controller in ASP.NET MVC term and so I don't want to put all request handlers into one file. If I moved the home.py to its parent folder, it works fine, but without a hierarchical folder structure, creating lots of files in one folder is not my preference. How can I achieve this? or maybe not a good practice in Django?

Thanks in advance,
Yoo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try popping a `__init__.py` into the directory `controllers`. This will make the directory a module python can see.

Answer (score 0):

It is typically not good practice to do it that way. But do what you feel comfortable with. Under controllers do you have a init py file? If not it might not be able to find the home.py file.

Can you post the contents of home.py? There might be something in there that is causing it not load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put 'community_web' into your installed apps section of your settings.py?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (                                                                 
    'django.contrib.auth',                                                         
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',                                                 
    'django.contrib.sessions',                                                     
    'django.contrib.sites',                                                        
    'django.contrib.admin',

    'community_web',
)
```